# WCF Named Pipe in Windows Service using App.Config

Tags: c#, wcf, app-config, named-pipes

I am frustrated. Okay, here is the error.

> There was no endpoint listening at net.pipe://localhost/MyIpcAppToService that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.

I finally got the App.Config file working, at least no complaints.

Current App.Config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's 
  app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2"/>
    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <services>
            <service behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceBehavior" name="MyService.Communication.IpcAppToService">
                <endpoint address="net.pipe://localhost/MyIpcAppToService" binding="wsDualHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="MyAppToServiceEndpointBinding" contract="MyIpc.IIpcAppToService"/>
                <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" name="mex" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
                <host>
                    <baseAddresses>
                        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8733/MyService/"/>
                    </baseAddresses>
                </host>
            </service>
  </services>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="MyServiceBehavior">
                    <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
                    <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment  to avoid disclosing exception information -->
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
                    <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <protocolMapping>
            <add scheme="http" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="MyAppToServiceEndpointBinding" />
        </protocolMapping>
        <bindings>
            <wsDualHttpBinding>
                <!-- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/wcf/wshttpbinding -->
                <binding name="MyAppToServiceEndpointBinding"
                                 transactionFlow="true"
                                 sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                                 maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
                                 messageEncoding="Mtom">
                </binding>
            </wsDualHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true">
            <baseAddressPrefixFilters>
                <add prefix="http://localhost:8733"/>
            </baseAddressPrefixFilters>
        </serviceHostingEnvironment>
    </system.serviceModel>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="countoffiles" value="7"/>
        <add key="logfilelocation" value="abc.txt"/>
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

I used to have:

```
<endpoint address="http://localhost:8733/MyIpcAppToService" ...
```

and in the Windows Service `OnStart()` event:

(this following code is now commented out, as of this question post, as the `App.config` file is supposed to start the named.pipe.)

```
public Boolean CreatePipeServer()
{
    string eventText = $"My Service: CommAppToService::CreatePipeServer(IPC App to Service){Environment.NewLine}";
    try
    {
        if (null != this.ServiceParent.HostIpcAppToService)
            this.ServiceParent.HostIpcAppToService = null;

        string pipeBaseAddress = @"net.pipe://localhost/MyIpcAppToService";
        this.ServiceParent.HostIpcAppToService = new ServiceHost(typeof(IpcAppToService), new Uri(pipeBaseAddress));
        NetNamedPipeBinding pipeBinding = new NetNamedPipeBinding()
        {
            //ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, Constants.My_TimeoutMsSendReceive),
            //SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, Constants.My_TimeoutMsSendReceive),
        };
        this.ServiceParent.HostIpcAppToService.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IIpcAppToService), pipeBinding, "MyIpcAppToService");
        this.ServiceParent.HostIpcAppToService.UnknownMessageReceived += HostIpcAppServer_UnknownMessageReceived;
        this.ServiceParent.HostIpcAppToService.Faulted += HostIpcAppServer_Faulted;
        this.ServiceParent.HostIpcAppToService.Closing += HostIpcAppServer_Closing;
        this.ServiceParent.HostIpcAppToService.Closed += HostIpcAppServer_Closed;

        this.IpcAppToService = new IpcAppToService();
        this.IpcAppToService.ApplyDispatchBehavior(this.ServiceParent.HostIpcAppToService);
        this.IpcAppToService.Validate(this.ServiceParent.HostIpcAppToService);
        this.ServiceParent.HostIpcAppToService.Open();

        return true;
    }
```

I read that the service will AUTOMATICALLY start services placed in the `App.Config` file, really the `MyExeName.exe.config` file. I kept looking at the code and saw that it was nearly identical, so I replaced the `http://` with `net.pipe://`.

Sadly, old code, new code, in between code, all nothing. I keep receiving the same error.

I use the following to connect to the service from my desktop application.

```
public static Boolean ConnectToService()
{
    try
    {
        var callback = new IpcCallbackAppToService();
        var context = new InstanceContext(callback);
        var pipeFactory = new DuplexChannelFactory<IIpcAppToService>(context, new NetNamedPipeBinding(), new EndpointAddress("net.pipe://localhost/MyIpcAppToService"));
        Program.HostIpcAppToService = pipeFactory.CreateChannel();
        Program.HostIpcAppToService.Connect();
        CommAppToService.IsPipeAppToService = true;

        return true;
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Log the exception.
        Errors.LogException(ex);
    }

    return false;
}
```

For whatever it is worth, here is:

Interface

```
[ServiceContract(SessionMode = SessionMode.Allowed, CallbackContract = typeof(IIpcCallbackAppToService))]
public interface IIpcAppToService
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = false)]
    [FaultContractAttribute(typeof(IpcAppToServiceFault))]
    UInt16 GetServiceId();

    ...
}
```

Service:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
public class IpcAppToService : IIpcAppToService, IErrorHandler
{
    public static IIpcCallbackAppToService Callback { get; set; } = null;

    public void OpenCallback()
    {
        IpcAppToService.Callback = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IIpcCallbackAppToService>();
    }

    public void CloseCallback()
    {
        IpcAppToService.Callback = null;
    }

    public void SendMessage(string message)
    {
        //MessageBox.Show(message);
    }

    public UInt16 GetServiceId()
    {
        return Constants.My_Id_AppToService;
    }

    ...
}
```

**Inner Exception** from my desktop WinForms Application
(Note, there were no further inner exceptions than this one.):

> "The pipe endpoint 'net.pipe://localhost/MyIpcAppToService' could not be found on your local machine."

Why do I keep seeing this error?

**UPDATE AFTER 1ST ANSWER**

The direction that I would like to take is opposite of the answer, yet the same, namely that the service starts with the `App.config` and the `client` uses C# code.

Sadly, I still get the same error.

**Revised Server Side App.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's 
  app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2"/>
    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <services>
            <service behaviorConfiguration="BehaviorMyService" name="MyService.Communication.IpcAppToService">
                <endpoint address="net.pipe://localhost/MyIpcAppToService"
                                    binding="netNamedPipeBinding"
                                    bindingConfiguration="EndpointBindingMyAppToService"
                                    contract="MyIpc.IIpcAppToService"
                                    />
                <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" name="mex" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
                <host>
                    <baseAddresses>
                        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8733/MyService/"/>
                    </baseAddresses>
                </host>
            </service>
        </services>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="BehaviorMyService">
                    <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"
                                                     httpsGetEnabled="true"
                                                     />
                    <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment  to avoid disclosing exception information -->
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
                    <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <bindings>
            <netNamedPipeBinding>
                <!-- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/wcf/wshttpbinding -->
                <binding name="EndpointBindingMyAppToService"
                                 closeTimeout="00:01:00"  
                                 openTimeout="00:01:00"   
                                 receiveTimeout="00:10:00"   
                                 sendTimeout="00:01:00"  
                                 transactionFlow="false"   
                                 transferMode="Buffered"   
                                 transactionProtocol="OleTransactions"  
                                 hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"   
                                 maxBufferPoolSize="524288"  
                                 maxBufferSize="65536"   
                                 maxConnections="10"   
                                 maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
                                 >
                    <security mode="None">
                        <transport protectionLevel="None" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </netNamedPipeBinding>
        </bindings>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true">
            <baseAddressPrefixFilters>
                <add prefix="http://localhost:8733"/>
            </baseAddressPrefixFilters>
        </serviceHostingEnvironment>
    </system.serviceModel>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="countoffiles" value="7"/>
        <add key="logfilelocation" value="abc.txt"/>
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

**Revised Client Side C# Code:**

```
var callback = new IpcCallbackAppToService();
InstanceContext context = new InstanceContext(callback);
NetNamedPipeBinding binding = new NetNamedPipeBinding();
binding.Security.Mode = NetNamedPipeSecurityMode.None;
EndpointAddress endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress("net.pipe://localhost/MyIpcAppToService");
var pipeFactory = new DuplexChannelFactory<IIpcAppToService>(context, binding, endpointAddress);
Program.HostIpcAppToService = pipeFactory.CreateChannel();
Program.HostIpcAppToService.Connect();
CommAppToService.IsPipeAppToService = true;
```

The service throws no exceptions that I can detect, as the EventViewer is clean, just the OnStart() successfully completed message. I know that the system processes the `App.config` file, as previously when I had errors, the `Windows Event Viewer` would keep complaining, but not anymore.

Here were some of the Microsoft docs that I used:

[netNamedPipeBinding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/netnamedpipebinding)

[netNamedPipeBinding2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/wcf/netnamedpipebinding)

I did try [IO Ninja](https://ioninja.com/), but specifying `\\.\pipe\MyIpcToService` for `File Stream`, `Pipe Listener`, and `Pipe Monitor`, but nothing shows there, even when I try to connect using my WinForms desktop application, which then throws the no pipe listener found exception.

What can be the problem?

Comment: So, is there an InnerException?

Comment: @stuartd In this case there was, but it said the same thing: ""The pipe endpoint 'net.pipe://localhost/MyIpcAppToService' could not be found on your local machine."

Comment: Right clicking on my client app and selecting Add > Add Service Reference and pasting "net.pipe://localhost/MyIpcAppToService/mex" yields the same message implying a server side issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<endpoint address="net.pipe://localhost/MyIpcAppToService" binding="wsDualHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="MyAppToServiceEndpointBinding" contract="MyIpc.IIpcAppToService"/>
```

Make sure that the service address is in the same form (transport protocol) as the binding type.

- TCP(net.tcp://localhost:8000/myservice) NetTcpBinding
- IPC(net.pipe://localhost/mypipe) NetNamedPipeBinding
- Http/Https(http://localhost:8000/myservice)
  Wshttpbinding,Wsdualhttpbinding,basichttpbinding
- WebSocket(ws://localhost:3434) Nethttpbinding
- MSMQ(net.msmq://localhost/private/myservice) NetMsmqBinding

we are supposed to use NetnamedPipeBinding for the service address. Please refer to my example.

---

**Updated**
I have a wcf service using NetNamedPipeBinding hosted in IIS, wish it is useful to you.
**Server(wcf service application)**

```
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string GetData(int value);
}
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        public string GetData(int value)
        {
            return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
        }
}
```

**Web.config(Server side)**

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="BehaviorMyService" name="WcfService1.Service1">
        <endpoint address="MyIpcAppToService"
                            binding="netNamedPipeBinding"
                            bindingConfiguration="EndpointBindingMyAppToService"
                            contract="WcfService1.IService1"
                                    />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" name="mex" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="BehaviorMyService">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <netNamedPipeBinding>
        <binding name="EndpointBindingMyAppToService"
                         closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                         openTimeout="00:01:00"
                         receiveTimeout="00:10:00"
                         sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                         transactionFlow="false"
                         transferMode="Buffered"
                         transactionProtocol="OleTransactions"
                         hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                         maxBufferPoolSize="524288"
                         maxConnections="10"
                         maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
                                 >
          <security mode="None">
            <transport protectionLevel="None" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </netNamedPipeBinding>
    </bindings>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true">
    </serviceHostingEnvironment>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

**Enable WCF new feature.**
[image]
[image]
**IIS site(enable net.pipe)**
[image]
[image]
**Client(console application)**

```
  ServiceReference1.Service1Client client = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
    var result = client.GetData(34);
    Console.WriteLine(result);
```

**Client app.config(auto-generated)**
I use the http address(service metadata GET address http://localhost:8733/Service1.svc?wsdl) to generated the configuration.

```
  <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <netNamedPipeBinding>
                <binding name="NetNamedPipeBinding_IService1">
                    <security mode="None" />
                </binding>
            </netNamedPipeBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="net.pipe://mynetpipe/Service1.svc/MyIpcAppToService"
                binding="netNamedPipeBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetNamedPipeBinding_IService1"
                contract="ServiceReference1.IService1" name="NetNamedPipeBinding_IService1" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
```

Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: I implemented what you suggested, see my updated question, just in the reverse, namely App.config for the server side and C# for the client side. I still get the same error. IO Ninja, not that I am an expert with that tool, is of no help debugging.

Comment: I commented out the service from the App.config on the server and added in the C# code. I kept the C# code on the client and received the same error. What is interesting is the second part of "there is no endpoint listening", which is "that could accept the message". That could mean a client side issue and that the server side is fine. I will investigate.

Comment: In my opinion, there is something wrong with publishing the service over NetPipe. I have updated my reply by modifying my example, wish it is useful to you.

Comment: I got the service working without the additional screenshots, though I had to use C# on the Windows Server and not the `App.config`. I could not get the service working with the config file. Now that I am writing, maybe I needed to create a .SVC file and not just 4 C# files. It is working. Thank you! The additional information is informative.